# Дублирование процессов крона

Tags: cron, php, linux

Проблема в следующем. По крону запускается скрипт для почтовой рассылки пользователям. Почему-то этот скрипт отрабатывает несколько раз. Ошибка в самом скрипте исключена - если запустить его через браузер, все срабатывает как надо. Тут проблема именно в кроне.

Задача выглядит так

```
30 12 * * * wget http://domain.com/cron/mail/notify >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Кажется, я поняла в чем может быть причина.
Судя по всему скрипт вылетает по таймауту, и через некоторое время он пробует перезапустится, при чем рекурсивно.
Попробую поставить set_time_limit(0); перед выполнением.

Answer (score 2):

Сам сталкивался. Проблему решил добавлением ключа, который не позволял раньше времени запускать еще раз скрипт. Хотя решение-то конечно хреновенькое.

Comment: что за ключ? можно поподробнее?

Comment: @anna241188 создается некий пустой файл, а перед созданием файла скрипт проверяет, сколько времени назад был создан файл, если меньше часа назад, то завершаем выполнение скрипта, если больше - то удаляем файл и соответственно заново его создаем.

Comment: ясно. это костыль, конечно, но, видимо, придется что-то подобное организовать.

Comment: @anna241188 ну понятное дело, что костыль) зато уже как 2 года работает без перебоев :D

Answer (score 0):

В каком кронтабе задача: в системном или пользовательском? Может, он запускается от пользователя и от root'а?

Comment: нет, запускается только от рута.

Answer (score 0):

Правильней было бы писать не пустой файл, а pid файл, и перед запуском проверять наличие запущенного процесса с соответствующим pid.
 Тогда будет больше уверенности в том что сейчас работает только 1 экземпляр скрипта.
При завершении работы скрипта - файл с pid удалять (предусмотреть его удаление и в случае аварийного завершения работы скрипта).